# '04 Corolla won't start sometimes

Tags: toyota, corolla, stall

I drive a manual stick shift and car's  engine sometimes dies. When this happens and I make the first attempt to restart the engine, it won't. It does start after I make sure to turn off radio and air conditioning. My question is, are all stick shifts this way?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you suggest it won't start, what exactly happens? You turn the key and ... *what?* Why does turning off the radio and A/C make it any better?

Comment: i think your battery or alternator is to blame here, first check all the wiring connections, i also had faced similar problem and the reason was a faulty battery

Answer (score 0):

No, not all stick-shifts are this way - when I stall my car, it starts rapidly even when lights heater etc are on. I suggest you may need to make sure the servicing is up to date : plugs, air filter etc then start to consider other causes, such as fuel feed problems, evaporation etc